# Exporting data as CSV with breaks Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, csv, newline, line-breaks

Here is my code in putting data inside the CSV. I am having trouble how to put linebreaks after every users.

```
$scope.users = [ {"users": "Sample A", "last_login": "2013-10-10 10:10:10"},
                 {"users": "Sample B", "last_login": "2013-10-10 10:30:10"}


var iCtr;
var loginUsers = $scope.users;

  $scope.loginHeader = ["Name","Last Login"];

  $scope.csvData = [];

    if (iCtr == 0) {
      for (var iCounter in loginUsers) {
        $scope.loginHeader.push(loginUsers[iCounter].name);
      }
    }

    var objCSV = {};
    var iCntr=0;  
      for (var iCounter in loginUsers) {
          objCSV[iCntr] = [loginUsers[iCounter].first_name + " " + loginUsers[iCounter].last_name, loginUsers[iCounter].lastLogin];
        }
        iCntr++;
      }
    $scope.csvData.push(objCSV);
```

Here is my desired output:

```
Name,Last login
Sample A,2013-10-10 10:10:10
Sample B,2013-10-10 10:30:10
```

Here is my output.

```
Name,Last login
Sample A,2013-10-10 10:10:10, Sample B,2013-10-10 10:30:10
```

Comment: Did you try with a \n ? you can also use the templating syntax (Ctrl+Alt+7 on Azerty keyboards) which will register your line returns

Comment: Add some more piece of code here. This code does not reflect exactly how your flow is executed. May be a plunkr is best here.

Comment: @trichetriche I even tried it and also the \r\n but the output is like this
`Name,Last login
Sample A,2013-10-10 10:10:10
, Sample B,2013-10-10 10:30:10`

and shows an empty cell on the next line if it is viewed in excel

Comment: And what about using the ```` quotes ? Just add a new line like you would do in a text editor and it should work